# How can I fix an issue occurring while installing the latest AMD graphics driver?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, proprietary

I installed the xorg-edgers ppa (and since removed it) and am now hitting the following errors when I try to install the official amd drivers. Any help to fix this would be great:

```
user@Ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
(Reading database ... 183095 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace fglrx 2:12.100-0ubuntu1 (using fglrx_12.100-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking replacement fglrx ...
Preparing to replace fglrx-amdcccle 2:12.100-0ubuntu1 (using fglrx-amdcccle_12.100-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement fglrx-amdcccle ...
Preparing to replace fglrx-dev 2:12.100-0ubuntu1 (using fglrx-dev_12.100-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement fglrx-dev ...
Setting up fglrx (2:12.100-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Loading new fglrx-12.100 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.5.0-22-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.5.0-22-generic
Done.

fglrx:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle (2:12.100-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fglrx-dev (2:12.100-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.7.0-7-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.7.0-7-generic: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
WARNING: Couldn't open directory /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not open /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep.temp for writing: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.7.0-7-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the old kernel was lingering in `/var/lib/initramfs-tools/`

Answer (score 1):

Try to install these packages

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases linux-headers-generic
```

if you have 64-bit Ubuntu also

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```